# Matrix factorizations over $GL_2$ of a real quadratic ring of integers

Tags: gr.group-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, matrices, number-fields, arithmetic-groups

> **tl;dr:** The groups $GL_2(K)$, or $SL_2(K)$, where $K = \mathbb{C,R}$ admits several factorizations (the polar decomposition,
>   the KAN decomposition, the Schur triangular form, etc). Those
>   factorizations are not available over discrete subgroups like
>   $$SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \subset SL_2(\mathbb{R}) \quad \mbox{ or } \quad
>  SL_2(\mathbb{Z}[i]) \subset SL_2(\mathbb{C}),$$ on account of the
>   orthogonal/unitary groups having finite intersection with those
>   groups. Are there analogues on the case of real quadratic integers? In
>   that case one can define analogues of the orthogonal/unitary groups with infinite cardinality.

**Context:** Let $1 < d$ be a positive, square free integer and let $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ be the ring of elements given by 
$$
  \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}] = \{n + \sqrt{d} \, m : n,m \in \mathbb{Z} \}.
$$
We will represent by $\sigma: \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}] \to \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ the nontrivial automorphism given by restriction the action of the Galois group and let $N: \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}] \to \mathbb{Z}$ be the function given by $N(x) = x \, \sigma(x)$.

A $2 \times 2$ matrix $x$ with values in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ is in invertible iff $N(\det(x)) = \pm 1$ and we denote the group of such matrices by $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}])$. The algebra of matrices over $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ has a natural anti-automorphism generalizing the usual ad joint of complex matrices, we will denote by 
$$
  \left( \begin{matrix}
    x_{1,1} & x_{1,2}\\
    x_{2,1} & x_{2,2}
  \end{matrix}  \right)^\sigma
  = 
  \left( \begin{matrix}
    \sigma(x_{1,1}) & \sigma(x_{2,1})\\
    \sigma(x_{2,1}) & \sigma(x_{2,2})
  \end{matrix} \right).
$$
We can define a $\sigma$-orthogonal subgroup by
$$
  O_2^\sigma(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}])
  = \big\{ x \in GL_2(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]) : {x^\sigma} x = 1 \big\}.
$$
It is clear that such group is infinite since diagonal multiplication by an element $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ with $N(\gamma) = 1$ induces an element in the group above. Similarly, we also have that any $x \in O_2^\sigma$ has $N(\det(x)) = 1$. It further seems that $x \in O_2^\sigma$ can be expressed as:
$$
  \left( \begin{matrix}
    \alpha & -\gamma \, \sigma(\beta)\\
    \beta & \gamma \, \sigma(\alpha)
  \end{matrix}  \right)
  \,
  \mbox{ with }
  \,
  \begin{cases}
    N(\gamma) = 1 \\
    N(\alpha) + N(\beta) = 1.
  \end{cases}
$$

In the case of complex matrices, we have several matrix factorization theorems, including:

- [Polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition): Every $x \in GL_2(\mathbb C)$ decomposes as $$x = u\, y,$$ with $u$ unitary and $y$ positive (in fact $y = |x^\ast x|^\frac 12$)
- [QR decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition)/[KAN decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iwasawa_decomposition): Every $x \in GL_2(\mathbb C)$ decomposes as $$x = u\, t,$$ with $u$ unitary and $t$ upper triangular.
- [Schur triangular form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition): Every $x \in GL_2(\mathbb C)$ can be expressed as $$x = u \, t \, u^\ast,$$ where $u$ is unitary and $t$ upper triangular.
- [Singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition)/[KAK decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_decomposition): Every $x \in GL_2(\mathbb C)$ can be expressed as $$x = u \, d \, v^\ast,$$ where $u, v$ are unitary and $d$ diagonal.

> **Question:** Is any of the decompositions above valid over $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}])$ after changing the group of unitaries by
>   the group $O_2^\sigma(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}])$? In particular, is there
>   a notion of positivity such that each coset $[O_2^\sigma \, x]$
>   contains positive element?

**Edit:** Arguments related to the incompleteness of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ can be used to exclude the Schur normal form and the KAK decomposition. The KAN is more subtle to exclude but there are counterexamples. That only leaves some form of polar decomposition as a possibility.